# How does Pusher authentication work?

Tags: pusher

I'm not sure I correctly understood how [authentication](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users) works in Pusher. Here's a scenario I'm concerned about:

1. User wants to subscribe to a private channel so the Pusher library calls my server in order to obtain an authentication token.
2. Server checks if the user is logged in and returns the token
3. Now the user gets this token and logs out from my app.
4. User is able to subscribe to the same private channel using the auth token from a different machine, even though they have been logged out.

Is the point 4 valid? Will it be possible to use the auth token after the user has been logged out from my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, option 4 isn't valid. An authentication token is created using a combination of the client's socket ID, channel name and secret. See: http://pusher.com/docs/auth_signatures

The socket ID is a globally unique identifier for the current client connection. If the same auth token were to be used on another machine the socket ID would be different so that auth token would not match the one that Pusher creates when checking the token sent as part of the subscription request from client.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I must have missed that part about the socket ID being used for creating an authentication token.

Comment: @janusz - could you please mark this as the correct answer (if you agree it is).